# Cannot import hamcrest MatchesPattern

Tags: mockito, hamcrest

I am trying to run something like this:

```
Matcher<String> mapKeyMatcher = Matchers.is("name");
Matcher<String> mapValueMatcher = Matchers.matchesPattern("Python\\d{2}x\\d{2}");

verify(mock_object, times(1)).install_tool(
        (Map<String, String>) argThat(
                hasEntry(mapKeyMatcher, mapValueMatcher)
        )
);
```

However I cannot find how to import `matchesPattern`
I am using *hamcrest-all* version 1.2, am I missing something ?

Comment: matchesPattern is not available in hamcrest 1.2., it appears somewhere in 2.x

Comment: Thanks, I tought hamcrest-all was the correct package, it is not marked as "deprecated" on maven central.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use hamcrest instead of hamcrest-all

```
    <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
    <java-hamcrest.version>2.0.0.0</java-hamcrest.version>

    <!-- HAMCREST -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>${java-hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```